# Lucene and Special Characters

Tags: c#, search, solr, lucene.net

I am not that expert user of stackoverflow but what i know is that my question is somewhat related to

[Lucene and Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732987/lucene-and-special-characters)

But i have a slight different environment.
I have an index with Lucene.NET but i am searching it with SOLR. Is it possible to search the special characters without re-indexing? while re-indexing i can change my analyzer but is it or not possible to search without re-indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set up your query analyzer in Solr to match the analyzer config used at index-time.

Solr has a very handy tool -- Field Analysis (solr/admin/analysis.jsp) -- for analyzing analyzer configurations. Check the verbose check boxes, and inspect how analyzers process your query terms. Lucid Imagination has [a section about it](http://search.lucidimagination.com/search/document/CDRG_ch03_3.2.3).

If you're not sure what analyzers were run at index time, then you will also have to inspect what the terms actually look like in the index (although it will likely be very hard to prove that your query analysis is correct). You can use the [LukeRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) for this.

If you can concluded a one-to-one mapping of terms (between index time analysis and query time analysis), then you're home safe, otherwise you might be better of re-indexing.

Comment: can you kindly elaborate your last line??? i feel as if i can't skip re-indexing ???